# Ubuntu 13.10 bootable USB shows black screen with blinking cursor only

Tags: 13.10, live-usb

I used this Universal USB Installer and ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso (MD5 verified)

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

But all I get is black screen with cursor blinking after BIOS's init texts. Yes, I've enabled boot from USB in BIOS.

Also used Ultra ISO to create a bootable USB for Ubuntu. I get some "Syslinux ..." message and nothing more.

My specs are:

- Intel dual core E5200 overclocked to 4.16 GHz
- Gigabyte EP45-DS3L
- Asus GTX660 video card
- 2 Hard drives and
- DDR2 800 MHz 4 GB

Windows XP, 7, 8.1, Kubuntu 9 x86(doesn't work any more) are all installed on this computer on different drives. Kubuntu probably stopped working after I changed video card from ATI to Nvidia.

I can boot from an old Kubuntu 9 x86 Live DVD.

How do I make it to work? Should I start dancing with buben?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've downloaded the 32 bit version of Linux Mint and it worked. Used Universal USB Installer to create bootable USB. I guess every 32 bit version of Linux will work

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before when I used Universal USB Installer, it got me nowhere. I think the problem is all the partitions and mbr on usb stick need to be deleted then formated with fat32 before using Universal Installer.

I found the other way around by installing Grub2 on usb stick and directly booting to Ubuntu ISO on my hd.

Comment: so how do I try this grub option?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was to use an USB memory with less memory (2Gb). However, Windows 7 was installed from the 16Gb USB memory without any problem.